# How to update view count as soon as i click that post?

Tags: laravel

There's a post and when the user clicks the post the view count should be incremented by 1.

I have already tried using the increment method.
It works but increments by 2.
The reason was as soon as i click the post the increments updates and again the increments methods executes. 
That means the increment works twice.

```
$view = PostAd::find($id);
$view->viewcount++;
$view->save();

return view('Frontend.pages.particular.particular',$data);
```

How can i only execute increment method for only once.

Comment: Well, what is the reason why it executes twice. If this is your code above the post view, it should only be executed once.

Answer (score 0):

Try using sessions

```
if (!Session::has('is_post') || Session::has('is_post') && Session::get('is_post') !== date('Y-m-d')) {
    $view = PostAd::find($id);
    $view->viewcount++;
    $view->save();

    Session::put('is_post', date('Y-m-d'));
}

return view('Frontend.pages.particular.particular',$data);
```